# Visual Studio 2019, trying to debug, MSVCP140_APP.dll not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I have created a Visual Studio 2019 solution under Windows 10, which contains 2 C++ projects. The first builds a dll, the second - an executable which, amongst others, uses the dll created by the first project.
I fail to start the executable with the error

`"The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140_APP.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."`

Both trying to debug using Visual Studio and trying to start an exe from the file browser fail.
Both Debug and Release modes fail.

Obviously I've tried to search for the solution and obviously I did not find it. Quite often UWP pops up but I have no idea why should I even know what it is if I have created the solution with the complete code from scratch...

Note: both projects use some external packages and everything worked fine under one project, before I did the split (in a different solution). After the split, the dll links to embree, and the exe to glfw and glew.

Comment: Check the output directories and project dependencies, see [Referencing Native DLLs or Static Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-organize-project-output-files-for-builds?view=msvc-160#referencing-native-dlls-or-static-libraries).

Comment: Yes, that's a UWP dependency.  Can't be found, it is supposed to be included with the appx package.  Only decent guess is that you picked the wrong project template to get started, it got to be a lot less intuitive in VS2019.  Be sure to choose "Dynamic-Link Library (DLL)"

Comment: Whether you are creating a uwp app? As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't simply launch the .exe of a UWP app as with Win32 applications. You should build the app in release mode and then you can deploy the generated APPX file.You need to side load it using the Visual Studio tools, or publish it to the store. Using the run-windows CLI command should do this for you, and after that it'll be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not creating a UWP app. I have just tried to create a new solution from scratch, started blank, added two project: one console app for an exe and used the "Dynamic-Link Library (DLL)" template for the dll. Same problem.

Comment: The error still is "MSVCP140_APP.dll was not found"? Could you please share a minimal demo about the issue to help us reproduce ?

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the problem. Seems that this error appears if embree3.dll is present, but not tbb.dll. I have no idea why it mentions MSVCP140_APP.dll...